# How to save solution gap (MIP Gap) and upper bound (objective bound) in gurobi?

Tags: python, java, c#, c, gurobi

I am using gurobi solver to solve MIP. It's an NP-hard formulation with many constraints. It takes a significantly large amount of time to find an optimal solution; so, I had to add time constraints to the problem. I do not require to save the solution, and value of variables obtained by gurobi in the specified time only, but require to save the upper bound, and solution gap as well which get reported when we solve MIP. May you provide a way to do that?

Comment: Which heuristic solution? Why not the solution found by Gurobi?

Comment: I had to add a time constraint. Gurobi has some inbuilt heuristic and heuristic solution was reported when we solve any MIP.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. You want to save solution values plus bound and incumbent objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, [Gurobi website](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/attributes.html) has given all the attributes and these can be used in some other languages, specifically **C, C++, C#, Java, and VBA** in addition to python; fortunately, there is attribute MIPGap and ObjBoundC that meets my specification. `model.Runtime` provides the time duration in which problem was solved; if `model.Runtime` >= Time Constraint then `model.MIPGap` provides ***MIPGap = abs(ObjVal - ObjBound)/ abs(ObjVal)***, and `model.ObjBoundC` provides ***'ObjBound'*** dubble.